# Can HTTP response body be empty when response header 'Content-Type' is set to 'application/json'?

Tags: javascript, json, http, http-headers, specifications

Is this allowed according to the specifications, or does it have to return a valid JSON (`[]` or `{}`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid JSON (RFC 7159) could be just JS Value (see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7159.html#values).

But no, and empty payload would not be valid according to the media type.